# Include period in macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a constant such as `foo.bar` via

```
#define foo.bar 42
```

When I try the above `foo` is expanded to `.bar 42`. Is there any way to escape the period or otherwise work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `.` is not allowed in macro names since they are identifiers and identifiers are not allowed to include a `.`. We can see this by going to [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.10` *Preprocessing directives* which includes the following grammar:

```
# define identifier replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and section `6.4.2` *Identifiers* covers what is a valid identifier.

Answer (score 3):

No, the period character is not permitted in C preprocessor macro names.

However, in this case you can achieve a similar effect without using the preprocessor:

```
static struct { int bar; } foo = {42};
```

Comment: But there's no way to make that an integral constant expression. Is there?

Comment: Well you could add `const` and get most of the way there. :)

Comment: In C++ it could be a compile-time constant if you made it a `static const int` member or `constexpr` object, but in C you are likely to accidentally declare a VLA or something :( .

Comment: @GregHewgill I actually wanted to go the other way. I was experimenting with using structs to emulate namespace and needed to make a integer constant to use for array lengths.

Answer (score 1):

In C, macro name must be valid identifier, which means you cannot use `.` in your macro name.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg says, the period character is not allowed in a macro name. However, macros are tricky. It is tempting to define `foo` to enter some intermediate state, and `bar` to resolve that state and perhaps generate `42`.

```
#define foo RESOLVE_STATE(
#define bar , 42 )
#define RESOLVE_STATE( DOT, RESOLUTION ) RESOLUTION
```

Unfortunately, the intermediate state has unfavorable semantics. It accepts macro arguments until it finds a matching right parenthesis. But the arguments are not expanded, so the parenthesis must occur literally. You could make it work with the input `foo.bar)` but that's not very useful.

To be clear, this is a proof of impossibility.